# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'No' to data type tinyint

Tags: sql-server

I have one SQL server table which has one tinyint column. The value of the column will be **0 or 1 or 2**.

```
  If it is "0", I have to show "No". 
  If it is "1", I have to show "Yes". 
  If it is 2, it needs to show just 2.
```

Below is my Query,

```
select 
case when flag=1 then 'Yes'
when flag=0 then 'No' 
else flag 
end flag
from Employee
```

When I execute this query I'm getting below exception,

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Yes' to data type tinyint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Else part is of type TinyInt other case statements return Varchar. This causes the issue. You can get rid of the issue by using the below.

(The SQL is similar to Juergen post but with minor change)

```
select case when flag=1 then 'Yes'
            when flag=0 then 'No' 
            else CAST(flag AS Varchar(3)) 
       end flag
from Employee
```

The size of Tiny Int is 0-255 so we can convert to Varchar(3)

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix the data types in a `case`. Cast the number output to a string

```
select case when flag=1 then 'Yes'
            when flag=0 then 'No' 
            else CAST(flag AS CHAR(1)) 
       end flag
from Employee
```

Comment: One *can* mix data types with a CASE expression but the final result will be converted to the data type of the highest precedence (`tinyint` in the original code).