# data type tinyint error with VBA when running SQL query

Tags: sql, vba

I am trying to run the below SQL in VBA, however I am getting a `conversion error converting varchar value '& Period &' to data type tinyint.

ST_PERIODNUMBER is a tinyint, with period have a max length of two, going from 1-12.

Running this SQL in SSMS, works as it is so I must be missing something in the VBA?

I have tried looking at [Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'No' to data type tinyint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856286/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-no-to-data-type-tinyint) but not sure how to fit this in?

Any help appreciated!

```
    Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set recset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        
'set parameters
    ServerSource = Sheets("Servers + Databases").Range("F27").Value            'choose the server the database is located
    Year = Sheets("Region").Range("C4").Value                                  'choose the year
    Period = Sheets("Region").Range("C5").Value                                'choose the period
    
'insert server name and database name
    sConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
               "Password=ExcelRep0rt;" & _
               "User ID=ExcelReport;" & _
               "Data Source=" & ServerSource & ";" & _
               "Use Encryption for Data=False"
    
    Conn.Open sConnect

'SQL query
    SQLQry = " SET NOCOUNT ON DECLARE @table table(dbname sysname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)" & _
             " INSERT INTO @table(dbname)" & _
             " SELECT NAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS FROM sys.databases where name like '%AccountsLive'" & _
             " DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;" & _
             " SELECT  @Sql = COALESCE(@Sql + ' UNION ALL ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '' ) +" & _
             " 'SELECT ST_ALOC_POINTER COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS ''Cust_Code'', ST_TRANTYPE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS ''Transaction'', ST_HEADER_REF COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS ''Reference'', ST_GROSS AS ''Local_Gross'', ST_CURRENCYCODE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS ''Currency'', ST_CURR_VALU AS ''Foreign_Gross'', ST_DESCRIPTION COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS ''Description'' FROM '" & _
             " + QUOTENAME(dbname) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS + '.dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS" & _
             " WHERE ST_YEAR = '' & Year & ''" & _
             " and ST_PERIODNUMBER = '' & Period & ''" & _
             " and ST_ALOC_POINTER like ''%LC%''" & _
             " and ST_GROSS <> ''0''" & _
             " and ST_TRANTYPE <> ''INV''" & _
             " and ST_TRANTYPE <> ''CRN''" & _
             " Union ALL" & _
             " SELECT ST_ALOC_POINTER COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS ''Cust_Code'', ST_TRANTYPE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS ''Transaction'', ST_HEADER_REF COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS ''Reference'', ST_GROSS AS ''Local_Gross'', ST_CURRENCYCODE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS ''Currency'', ST_CURR_VALU AS ''Foreign_Gross'', ST_DESCRIPTION COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS ''Description'' FROM '" & _
             " + QUOTENAME(dbname) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS + '.dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS" & _
             " WHERE ST_YEAR = '' & Year & ''" & _
             " and ST_PERIODNUMBER = '' & Period & ''" & _
             " and ST_ALOC_POINTER like ''%CR%''" & _
             " and ST_GROSS <> ''0''" & _
             " and ST_TRANTYPE <> ''INV''" & _
             " and ST_TRANTYPE <> ''CRN'''" & _
             " FROM    @table" & _
             " EXEC( @Sql );"
    
'import table - choose range of where to put the table
    Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset
        recset.Open SQLQry, Conn
        Range("B10").CopyFromRecordset recset
        recset.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
" and ST_PERIODNUMBER = '' & Period & ''" & _
```

should be

```
" and ST_PERIODNUMBER = '" & Period & "'" & _
```

Comment: thanks tim - i knew it would be something as simple as that! however, i just needed to put `" and ST_PERIODNUMBER = " & Period & "" & _` otherwise i get an `incorrect syntax near X` but thanks for leading me down the right path!

Comment: Yes - no quotes for numeric values.  Missed that part.

Comment: actually, just do add to this, `" WHERE ST_YEAR = '' & Year & ''" & _` needed to be `" WHERE ST_YEAR = ''" & Year & "''" & ` ....just for people in the future looking at this!